# Answering request with multipart/form-data in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data

I'm trying to communicate with an old PHP service, which uses json in multipart/form-data. The server send a POST request to my express.js server with some data and wait me to answer the same way.

Parsing the requests is easy using multer. But I'm not able to send responses in same format, I'm trying to do this with form-data module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) but I could use any other solution. I need to create a multipart/form-data response and send it back to the server.

Example code:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var FormData = require('form-data');

var app = express();


app.post('/', multer().array(), function (req, res) {
  //Request is well handled and req.body contains fields from request
  //try to send response params in same multipart/form-data format.

  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('key', 'value');
  form.append('key2', 'value');
  res.set(form.getHeaders()); //Set content header
  res.set('content-length', ''+form.getLengthSync()); //Set length header
  form.pipe(res);  //Pipe form stream into response, response is send, but format is wrong.
});
```

Any advice? I have seen lot of examples of multipart/form-data requests parsing but I need to send the responses to the server in same format.

Comment: Is your question about generating a response with the correct headers, or how to encode data for `multipart/form-data`?